# how to tell auto to deduce a non reference type for element of vector<bool>

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> b(5,false);
    auto b0=b[0];
    cout<<b0;
    b[0]=true;
    cout<<b0;
    std::vector<int> i(5,false);
    auto i0=i[0];
    cout<<i0;
    i[0]=true;
    cout<<i0;

    return 0;
}

0100
```

The variable b0 is with reference type (std::_Bit_reference) while i0 is normal int. What is the right grammar to tell auto to deduce some non reference type, for example, bool?

Comment: I don't think you can make this happen because `auto` specifically means "pick up whatever the type of the thing is" and `vector<bool>` is an odd one. But perhaps I'm mistaken?

Comment: Maybe the operator+ tool can help here? The real solution though is to avoid `vector<bool>`. Try `vector<Bool>` with `enum class Bool { False, True };`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `std::_Bit_reference`, because `std::vector` has a "possibly" space-efficient implementation for `bool` template-specialization (that is `std::vector<bool>`).

As [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), vector stores values in bits instead of bytes:

> The manner in which std::vector is made space efficient (as well as whether it is optimized at all) is implementation defined. One potential optimization involves coalescing vector elements such that each element occupies a single bit instead of sizeof(bool) bytes.

As [templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef) has said, `auto` takes the first thing it can deduce, which just happens to be some fancy type for getting bools from bits.

> Exposes class std::vector::reference as a method of accessing individual bits. In particular, objects of this class are returned by operator[] by value.
>
> ---

```
>operator bool() const;
>(until C++11)
>operator bool() const noexcept;
>(since C++11)
>Returns the value of the referenced bit.
```

It is implicitly convertable to bools (AFAIK), so you should not have any concerns about passing it to functions that require `bool` arguments.

Comment: I'll never stop wondering why this abomination, `std::vector<bool>`, is still part of STL.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I suppose it would be better to add some other specialization to explicitly state that bools are optimized to be stored as bits. and just `std::vector<bool>` to be as a usual vector I think.

Comment: Yup, it is `std::bitset<N>`. Only constraint, N is fixed at compile time. Oh and it sucks in another manner. It isn't constexpr when it could be .

Answer (score 0):

`auto` uses the template rules for type deduction. You cannot change that. If that's not what you want, then don't use `auto` and instead write out the type by hand

Answer (score -1):

even remove_reference can not remove reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> b(5,false);
    std::remove_reference< decltype(b[0])>::type b0=b[0];
    cout<<typeid(b0).name()<< b0;
    b[0]=true;
    cout<<b0;
    return 0;
}

St14_Bit_reference01
```

Comment: There is absolutely no sence in using `std::remove_reference`, since it removes a reference qualifier which `std::_Bit_reference` obviously does not have. `std::remove_reference` used on `int&` will simply remove `&`. But `std::_Bit_reference` is not qualified as a reference - you can not remove `&` when there is none. This class is just an *implementation* to *simulate* a reference *behaviour*.